# Count of each distinct value in data field

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I'm looking to write a query which will return each district value in the table along with the count of each distinct value for a given time period

I am Currently using the following query

```
Select count(distinct account_type)
From Table_1
Where date between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31' and 
account_type = '0' and 
account_type = '1' and 
account_type = '2' and
account_type = '3' and
account_type = '4'
```

The result set that I'm looking for is as follows

```
account_type     Count
0                 123
1                 456                
2                 789
3                 101112
4                 131415
```

The result set that I get is

```
account_type 
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE-clause excludes all elements since they cannot be of type 0 and 1 (etc.) contemporarily.
Furthermore, by means of `count(distinct account_type)` you get the number of distinct account types; not the number of elements for each account type.
Try this:

```
SELECT   account_type,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     table_1
WHERE    date BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31'
  AND    account_type IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4')
GROUP BY account_type
ORDER BY account_type;
```

In case the `account_type` is always a single character (so for example '06' doesn't exist), you can also use:

```
AND account_type BETWEEN '0' AND '4'
```